# Pandas Convert the prints to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a code and the prints look pretty weird. i want to fix it

*The Prints

```
     Matching      Score
0  john carry  73.684211
       Matching  Score
0  alex midlane   80.0
       Matching  Score
0  alex midlane   50.0
      Matching      Score
0  robert patt  53.333333
      Matching      Score
0  robert patt  70.588235
      Matching  Score
0  david baker  100.0
```

*I need this format

```
  | Matching     |   Score    |
  | ------------ | -----------|
  | john carry   |  73.684211 |
  | alex midlane |  80.0      |
  | alex midlane |  50.0      |
  | robert patt  |  53.333333 |
  | robert patt  |  70.588235 |
  | david baker  |  100.0     |
```

*My Code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from rapidfuzz import process, fuzz
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "NameTest": ["john carry", "alex midlane", "robert patt", "david baker", np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    "Name": ["john carrt", "john crat", "alex mid", "alex", "patt", "robert", "david baker"]
})

NameTests = [name for name in df["NameTest"] if isinstance(name, str)]

for Name in df["Name"]:
    if isinstance(Name, str):
        match = process.extractOne(
            Name, NameTests,
            scorer=fuzz.ratio,
            processor=None,
            score_cutoff=10)
        data = {'Matching': [match[0]],
                'Score': [match[1]]}
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

    print(df1)
```

I have tried many ways. but got the same prints

thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new dataframe in each loop. You can store the result in a global dict and create dataframe from that dict after the loop.

```py
data = {'Matching': [], 'Score': []}

for Name in df["Name"]:
    if isinstance(Name, str):
        match = process.extractOne(
            Name, NameTests,
            scorer=fuzz.ratio,
            processor=None,
            score_cutoff=10)
        data['Matching'].append(match[0])
        data['Score'].append(match[1])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an array or a list in order to keep all the data (I use an array) because you creating a dataframe in each loop

```
data = []
for Name in df["Name"]:
    if isinstance(Name, str):
        match = process.extractOne(
            Name, NameTests,
            scorer=fuzz.ratio,
            processor=None,
            score_cutoff=10)
        print(match[0])
        data.append({'Matching': match[0],
                'Score': match[1]})
        
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df1)
```

Here is the output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8IJK.png)